# Интент для создания фотографии всегда возвращает null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, photo

Не понимаю, почему после создания фотографии всегда `Intent` в `onActivityResult()` равен `null`. 
Первым делом я добавил Provider в Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

`@xml/file_paths` выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
</paths>
```

Для запуска интента с камерой выполняется следующий код:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = createImageFile();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                ex.getMessage();
                            }

                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                                        "com.mydomain.fileprovider",
                                        photoFile);
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_FOR_AVATAR_UPLOAD_FROM_GALLERY);
                            }
                        }
```

Метод `createImageFile()`:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

В конечном итоге мне нужно получить File для загрузки новой фотографии на сервер. Следующий код находится в `onActivityResult()`:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_FOR_AVATAR_UPLOAD_FROM_CAMERA:
            if (data != null) {
                Uri avatarUri = data.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(avatarUri);
                App.Log(path);
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File(path);
                uploadAvatar(file);
            }
            break;
```

Но он не исполняется из-за того, что data всегда равна null. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: В приведенном коде ``data`` существует только в блоке ``if (data != null)``. А прежде чем использовать переменную, нужно присвоить ей значение. Где у вас это происходит?

Comment: data приходит как параметр в onActivityResult (обновил код)

Comment: <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
На сохранение? Вот все разрешения, которые есть у меня

Comment: `<files-path name="my_images" path="/"/>` так попробуйте

Comment: Ничего не поменялось

Comment: а где вы `data` то задаете, покажите? и проверьте, записывается ли файл?

Comment: Не уверен, что он должен возвращать `uri`, который Вы же ему и передали. То есть Вы можете отдать серверу файл, который вернул метод `createImageFile()`. Естественно убедившись, что он записан (как минимум в  `onActivityResult` должен прийти `resultCode == OK`

Comment: у меня создается картинка, приходит RESULT_OK, но я не понимаю как мне получить ссылку на файл

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile();` - Вы её создаёте самолично, только чтобы она была доступна в другом методе нужно сделать её полем класса

Comment: Получилось, большое вам спасибо